# check if switch is on boolean watchkit

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, watchkit, apple-watch

In Swift using iOS I used to be able to do:

```
if mySwitch.on {

myLabel.text = "The Switch Is In The On Position!"

}else{

myLabel.text = "The Switch Is In The Off Position!"


}
```

but how do I  do `if mySwitch.on {}` in WatchKit Swift

I saw on apple it told me `if mySwitch.setOn(on: Bool)` but how do I check to see if 'mySwitch' is in the off or on position.

Does anyone know the correct boolean method?

Thanks,

George Barlow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such property which helps you to check the current state.

But you can create an `IBAction` for your switch like that:

```
@IBAction func switchAction(value: Bool) {
    if value{
        myLabel.text = "The Switch Is In The On Position!"
    }else{
        myLabel.text = "The Switch Is In The Off Position!"
    }
}
```

As you see, the parameter is a bool which indicates if it's on or off(true = on)

[Check the Apple Documentation about that.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceSwitch_class/)